# plottext on horizontal bar in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I am trying to plot the barchart and want to show the percentage on horizontal line end.. Not able to get ..whats the mistake

```
y <- c('Others(27%)','Environment','Family Life & children','Combating terrorism','Pensions',
   'Europe', 'Housing', 'Education', 'Tax','Benefits','Immigration & Assylum','Health','Economy')
x <- c(27,10,12,15,18,20,20,21,21,25,42,46,49)

mylabels <- c('....27%','10%','12%','15%','18%','20%','20%','21%','21%','25%','42%','46%','49%')

par(mar=c(5,10,4,2)+0.1)
usr <- par( "usr" )
my_bar<-barplot(x,main="British Voters Election Priority (2015)", horiz=TRUE,las = 1,
        names.arg=y, xlim=c(0, 60), border = 'black',         
col=rev(topo.colors(14)),
        xlab="Percentage (%)")  
abline(v=x, col='grey', type="l", lty=2)
#text(myvect1, b[1,], mylabels, col="white", adj=1) 
text(my_bar, mylabels, cex=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you  want the numbers to be displayed at the end of the bars, just extract the numeric characters out of "mylabels" to get the appropiate x-coordinates and set pos = 4 to display them on the right of the bars. As for the colours for the bars, just pick some palette that suits your wishes or specify all 13 colors manually. There are tons of cheatsheets throughout the web with different color patterns for R.

```
 my_bar<-barplot(x,main="British Voters Election Priority (2015)",      horiz=TRUE,las = 1,
            names.arg=y, xlim=c(0, 60), border = 'black',         
            col = palette(rainbow(13)),
            xlab="Percentage (%)")  
 abline(v=x, col='grey', type="l", lty=2)
 #text(myvect1, b[1,], mylabels, col="white", adj=1) 
 text(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", mylabels)), my_bar, mylabels, cex=1, pos = 4)
```

[image]

Comment: In case any of these answers was helpful to you, please consider to accept it or upvote it. (See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify x-coordinates for where the tekst should be plotted. Your code now took the values of my_bar for both the x-coordinates and the y-coordinates. If I am correct you want something like this.

[image]

Just use this line of code at the end in order to get that:

```
text(60, my_bar, mylabels, cex=1, pos = 2)
```

Comment: thanx a ton...how can I add value at the end of each bar outside

Comment: How can i distinguish colors of first two bars.. They seem almost similar